# htaccess to load a template.php file only if a file exists in requested url

Tags: php, json, .htaccess

I'd like to get htaccess to load a template.php file that acts as my front controller, *only* if a gallery.json file exists in the requested url

for example, if I went to mysite.com/test and within the test folder I had a gallery.json file, I want template.php to read that gallery.json file

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test/gallery.json  -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/test/template.php
RewriteRule  ^(.*)  /test/anormalfile.php [L]
```

Here you will be able to check if the `gallery.json` file is present in the test directory. If it is then load `template.php`, else load `anormalfile.php`. Hopefully this helped you.

The RewriteRule flag that would be most useful to you is called Skip. It's similar to an if statement in most coding languages. It will do a check then ignore a certain amount of lines depending on what you tell it to do. You can read more about it [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s).

Comment: hmm, i dont have a lot of experience with .htaccess, how would i get it to skip those if an index.html or index.php exists in the folder?

Comment: Did you try my example?